# update json replacing variable input from form in php

Tags: php, json

Greeting, I'm new to PHP, and currently looking for a way to edit json.
I have a form to input the key that wants to edit. I echo the input from form and successfully got the output showing but it didn't pass to json file to update. The code is as below.

```
function testfun()
{
    // read file
    $data = file_get_contents('Book2.json');

    // decode json to array
    $json_arr = json_decode($data, true);

    foreach ($json_arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['CELL_NAME'] == $_POST['in_cell']) {
            $json_arr[$key]['@25'] = $_POST['in_remark'];
        }
    }

    // encode array to json and save to file

    file_put_contents('Book2.json', json_encode($json_arr));
}
//you this post contain test?
//test is the the button when i submit the form

if (array_key_exists('test',$_POST))
{
    testfun();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: seems like your code is okay. are you sure json file didn't change?

Comment: Can you share var_dump($_POST) ?

Comment: I don't manage to understand your exact problem. Those the `testfun` being called? can you please print the `$json_arr` before and after the `for` loop?

Comment: @david yes it didn't change

Comment: Can you please share example (short one) of the `$json_arr`?

Comment: @DavidWinder ya i try to echo the $_POST['in_cell'] and $_POST['in_remark'] in the webpage it shows the input that I key in earlier, but doesn't update on the json

Comment: I ask for the `$json_arr` var

Comment: @DavidWinder

{"CELL_NAME":"1234A","@25":"remark value"} heres the sample,
$json_arr[$key]['@25'] is the "remark value"

Comment: @user10417098 `{"CELL_NAME":"1234A","@25":"remark value"}` this is the `$json_arr` content? or the `$value` content?
Can you please share the entire `$json_arr` content?

Comment: @DavidWinder yes its the $json_arr content, the entire content is the same format and I not able to share all. It's the same format but more rows.

Comment: @user10417098 So there is your problem:  `$json_arr[$key]['@25'] ` is not exist - you probably want to change the  `$json_arr['@25'] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention in the comments, the content of the `$json_arr` is:

```
{"CELL_NAME":"1234A","@25":"remark value"}
```

So when you trying to access in:

```
 foreach ($json_arr as $key => $value) {
     if ($value['CELL_NAME'] == $_POST['in_cell']) {
         $json_arr[$key]['@25'] = $_POST['in_remark'];
     }
 }
```

it has no key for `$value` at `CELL_NAME` key.

I guess your `$data` from the file should be like that (an array of JSONs):

```
$data = '[{"CELL_NAME":"1234A","@25":"remark value"}, {"CELL_NAME":"1234B","@25":"remark value"}]';
```

Now you can do this and it will work:

```
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['CELL_NAME'] == "1234A") // you can change with $_POST['in_cell']
        $arr[$key]['@25'] = "test"; // you can change with $_POST['in_remark']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my code.

```
 function testfun()
{
// read file
$data = file_get_contents('Book2.json');

// decode json to array
$json_arr = array(json_decode($data, true));
foreach ($json_arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['CELL_NAME'] == $_POST['in_cell']) {
    $json_arr[$key]['@25'] = $_POST['in_remark'];
    }
}

// encode array to json and save to file

file_put_contents('Book2.json', json_encode($json_arr));
}


if (array_key_exists('test',$_POST))
{
    testfun();
}
```

Comment: Foreach $json_arr because it's a one-dimensional array $value that only outputs the result directly, so no key value is required

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: Change here `$json_arr = array(json_decode($data, true));`@user10417098

Comment: What? I didn't cast to array - I think his input is corrupted

Comment: You just need to change `$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);` of your code to `$json_arr = array(json_decode($data, true))`.

Comment: I understand - that also solve the issue but I think it wasn't the original intention of the code...

Comment: Obviously, that's the fact. @David Winder

Comment: Who do you think is the answer to your problem? @user10417098

Comment: Oh, I really have nothing to say.

Comment: If the array wrapping was the issue so better solution will be to skip the foreach loop but I still think the json file should include array of jsons and not a single json object

Comment: In the long run, you and I are not exactly right and wrong.
You only modify the result, and I modified it from the source of the problem and did not save the result. But my answer reminds you, and this is also true.
The real mistake is the person asking questions.  @ David Winder

Comment: @J.Doe I still believe I gave detail answer and the more rigth one for this question - I can tell you that my post was not influenced by your. However, I will upvote your answer as a token of appreciation and professional courtesy